# Cannot output log4j message to a file - Grails

Tags: grails, log4j

I configured log4j.

I COULD output the debug message to the console, but NOT to a file.

How can I output log4j message to a file?

My Config.groovy is below

```
log4j.main = {
    appenders {
        console     name:'stdout', 
                    layout: pattern(conversionPattern: "[%d{HH:mm:ss:SSS}] %-5p %c{2}: %m%n")
        appender    new DailyRollingFileAppender( name: "file",
                        file: "/usr/local/myapp/app.log",
                        datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd",
                        layout: pattern(conversionPattern: "[%d{HH:mm:ss:SSS}] %-5p %c{2}: %m%n")
                    )
        rollingFile name:"stacktrace",
                    file:"/usr/local/myapp/stacktrace.log",
                    maxFileSize:'10MB' 
    }
    root {
        environments {
            production {
                error 'file', 'stacktrace'
                debug 'stacktrace'
                additivity = false }
            development{
                error 'stdout', 'file', 'stacktrace'
                debug 'stdout', 'stacktrace'
                warn 'stdout', 'stacktrace'
                additivity = false } 
    }    }    
    error  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',        // controllers
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages',          // GSP
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh',       // layouts
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping',        // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons',            // core /  classloading
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins',            // plugins
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate',      // hibernate integration
           'org.springframework',
           'org.hibernate',
           'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate',
           'StackTrace'

    debug   'grails.app.controllers',
            'grails.app.domain',
            'grails.app.services'

    warn    'org.springframework',
            'org.hibernate',
            'grails.plugins.springsecurity',
            'groovyx.net.http'
    }
```

And I put a log on a controller like below

```
pacakege hoge
class TestController {
    def test(){ test2() }
    private test2(){ log.debug "test" }
    index(){ }
}
```

**How can I output the log?**

---

### **UPDATE**

The log file was created, but no messages in the file.
Just created empty files.

I changed the permission of the files, but no change.

Comment: Try this debug "file" "grails.app.controllers" - you have configured root logger to log to file appenders only in prod env. thts probably the reason. Try specifying the appender for all controllers like i mentioned above

Comment: Also why log4j.main = {} it should be just log4j = {} i think.

Comment: Sorry, the development part was missed. I added that part.

Comment: log4j.main = {} was added by log4j plugin at the time of initial compile, and then I have not touched the code.

Comment: I tried this debug "file" "grails.app.controllers", but did not work.

Comment: Remove grails.app from info and give it a go. I did face the same issue. When you declare the same package at different levels, it doesn't seem to log the information.

Comment: I simplified the code, still it does not work

Comment: I deleted info, but does not work.

Comment: the log files were created, but no message in them